# Android save Live Streaming Recording

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming

I am working on an application that needs to record audio streams from online radio, either live (that broadcasts to everybody) or on demand (like last.fm and pandora), is there any tool that can help me do so, or an opensource code that does so,please if any body knows how this can be done help.

Thanks